# How to write a self join query to check to conditions on same entity/field

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have the following schema
[image]

so if the user wants the video to be **private he sends '1'** while adding the video, So that the video is available to only that particular user

If the users chooses **0 then the video is made available to all users**.

**Here is sample data:**
[image]

I have a large set of information, and so i want to query only 20-20 records using **limit**

Query i tried

```
select * from test where userid="2" and public/private ="0"
```

But this will return only one record i.e videoid='1'

If i query like

```
select * from test where userid=4 and public/private='1'
```

i also want videoid 1,2 as result as they are public

Hope you understand what i mean!
Can you help me to design the query..

Comment: Sure Stack Overflow community can help, please share with us the query that you have managed to write till now.

Comment: You have shown the sample data, could you show the possible output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all private listings for that user and and all public listings for any user

```
select * from test where userid="2" or public/private ="0"
```

Comment: Ahh thats what i want. i dint even try to think of a simple OR. I was thinking of a selfjoin. Many thanks